# Google maps api: what are xa and pa in get bounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The Api reference tells me that getBounds() returns the coordinates for SW and NE extremes. When I call it, it returns me with a object with xa and pa as keys, each of them having j and k as keys where the coordinates are, seemingly randomly. I have tried to find them in the documentation but get nothing. I can write out custom code to find min and max to determine them myself, but I'm wondering if I can know what they mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

Answer (score 2):

They are "undocumented properties".  Do **not** use them in your code (they change with API releases).

Use the [documented methods of the google.maps.LatLngBounds object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

```
getNorthEast() | LatLng | Returns the north-east corner of this bounds.
getSouthWest() | LatLng | Returns the south-west corner of this bounds.
```